# How can I get the word count of each line from an extracted PDF file in Matlab Text Analytics

Tags: matlab, word-count

I’m learning Matlab learning text analytics, and have extracted text from a PDF file with many lines/entries of comments. I want to get the word count of each line, the average word count all lines, and the number of lines that only has one word. Is this possible?

I tried `nWords=numel(strsplit(str))` and `tokenizedDocument`, but it would only show the overall word count...

Comment: See the StackOverflow guide below. I think, your ask can be presented with minimal code in a sufficiently reproducible form. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This question is very broad - which bit are you stuck on? From your "I tried" it seems like you might already have the text stored in the variable `str`, in which case this isn't actually about interacting with the PDF at all?